# Why does this code segfault on the w.show() call?

Tags: c++, qt

Subject says it all, here is the code:

I am using windows 7 64-bit with qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw482_opengl-5.3.1

I posted the effected code below. When debugging the crash, I get a segfault on the w.show() line in the main.cpp file

EDIT:
Sorry forget to add that it does not crash if I comment out the line:

```
//mainLayout->addLayout(oldLayout,0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
```

it then corectly shows the mainwindow with the widget, but when I try to add a layout to the layout, it crashes...

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QString>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    setupWidgets();    
}


void MainWindow::setupWidgets() {

    mainWidget = new QWidget;
    mainLayout = new QGridLayout;

    setupOld();    

    setCentralWidget(mainWidget);
    mainWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    mainLayout->addLayout(oldLayout,0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
}

void MainWindow::setupOld() {
    oldLayout = new QGridLayout;

    oldX = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    oldX->setRange(minNum,maxNum);
    oldX->setDecimals(precision);
    oldX->setSuffix(suffix);

    oldY = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    oldY->setRange(minNum,maxNum);
    oldY->setDecimals(precision);
    oldY->setSuffix(suffix);

    oldZ = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    oldZ->setRange(minNum,maxNum);
    oldZ->setDecimals(precision);
    oldZ->setSuffix(suffix);

    QLabel lblX, lblY, lblZ;
    lblX.setText("Old X Coord: ");
    lblY.setText("Old Y Coord: ");
    lblZ.setText("Old Z Coord: ");

    oldLayout->addWidget(&lblX,0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    oldLayout->addWidget(oldX,0,1,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    oldLayout->addWidget(&lblY,1,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    oldLayout->addWidget(oldY,1,1,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    oldLayout->addWidget(&lblZ,2,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
    oldLayout->addWidget(oldZ,2,1,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
}
```

Comment: this is usually caused by null pointer, check your object's properties

Comment: Where is the default constructor ?

Comment: @quantdev it's usually a `MainWindow(QWidget* parent=0)` (aka using a default parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is in the following code:

```
QLabel lblX, lblY, lblZ;
[..]
oldLayout->addWidget(&lblX,0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
```

You create label objects in the stack and use them in your layout. Labels are deleting after the execution exists the `MainWindow::setupOld()` function, so your layout contains references to the deleted objects.

To fix the problem you need to create your labels allocating memory from the heap as you do for `QDoubleSpinBox`es:

```
QLabel *lblX = new QLabel("Old X Coord: ");
[..]
oldLayout->addWidget(lblX,0,0,1,1,Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Comment: @vahancho Thanks, yes created pointer labels and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The below works. Note how I've factored out repetitive code, put all the objects as direct members of `MainWindow`, and leveraged the initializer list in the constructor.

You **don't have to use `QMainWindow`** if you don't wish to use its other features (docking areas, status bar, etc.). In the code below, you could easily replace `QMainWindow` with `QWidget`, with following other changes:

1. Set the layout on `this` instead of `m_central`,
2. Remove the `setCentralWidget` call.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
   QWidget m_central;
   QGridLayout m_centralLayout;
   QDoubleSpinBox m_oldX, m_oldY, m_oldZ;
   QLabel m_lblX, m_lblY, m_lblZ;
public:
   MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags flags = 0);
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent, Qt::WindowFlags flags) :
   QMainWindow(parent, flags),
   m_centralLayout(&m_central),
   m_lblX("Old X Coord: "),
   m_lblY("Old Y Coord: "),
   m_lblZ("Old Z Coord: ")
{
   QList<QDoubleSpinBox*> spins;
   spins << &m_oldX << &m_oldY << &m_oldZ;
   int i = 0;
   foreach (QDoubleSpinBox * spin, spins) {
      spin->setRange(0.0, 1.0);
      spin->setDecimals(3);
      spin->setSuffix(" km");
      m_centralLayout.addWidget(spin, i++, 1);
   }

   m_centralLayout.addWidget(&m_lblX, 0, 0);
   m_centralLayout.addWidget(&m_lblY, 1, 0);
   m_centralLayout.addWidget(&m_lblZ, 2, 0);

   setCentralWidget(&m_central);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```